# Keep role permissions (more than 50) in session Or query from database every time?

Tags: session, web-applications

I have a web application with user, policy, user-policy-permission database. Each user may have more than 50 permissions (such as startVM, stopVM, runVM, terminateVM...).

After login, users can only do the operations allowed by policies. I am wondering which is better?
 save policies in session?  Or Query from database real-time?

Comment: How concerned are you with the possibility that permissions might become out of date during a session? If they do, how damaging is it that a user might be allowed to do something after the permission has been changed to prohibit them from doing that?

Comment: In the reverse direction, what impact will it have on performance if you query every time?

Comment: The super admin may change the user permissions when user is still in the session. And query from database is not slow, the performance is acceptable.

Comment: If performance is acceptable, then querying every time is most likely the cleaner option.